# Cómo obtener horas de encendido de un Disco Duro en Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, hardware

[image: Este es el Valor que necesito obtener]Pudieran Ayudarme a Obtener las Horas de encendido que pueda tener un Disco Duro de nuesta PC,progragmaticamente en Delphi, Digamos por ejemplo del Disco 0 o 'C'
Ayuda !!!

Answer (score 0):

Deberías revisar si utilizando WMI puedes acceder a esa información o el un cálculo aproximado que devuelve esa aplicación.

Puedes revisar las siguientes clases, a ver si hay qlguna propiedad que pueda ayudarte:

[Win32_LogicalDisk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk)
[Win32_DiskDrive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive)

Comment: Gracias Colega por la luz, pero lo cierto es que no tengo mucha experiencias como poder implementarla por mi mismo, agradeceria mucho que me den al menos un codigo de ejemplo lo mas simple posible. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCuellar La documentación era para que revisaras si hay alguna propiedad que te permita acceder a ese valor. Lee y busca, eso es un punto de partida. Si la encuentras, el código para obtenerla mediante WMI es sencillo y lo podemos poner. Lo que no tengo claro 100% es si ese valor es realmente una propiedad que se puede obtener o es un cálculo aproximativo que hace ese programa (del que has puesto la imagen).